# How should i draw a Peano Curve?

Tags: python, recursion, turtle-graphics, fractals

This is my code for drawing a peano curve using python turtle in Visual Studio Code. I can get level 1 just fine but other than that it does not really repeat the shape correctly for the subsequent levels. Any suggestions?

```
from turtle import *
def peano(level, length):
    if level == 1:
       print(rt(45), fd(length/3), rt(90), fd(length/3), lt(90), fd(length/3))
       print(lt(90), fd(length/3), lt(90), fd(length/3), rt(90), fd(length/3))
       print(rt(90), fd(length/3), rt(90), fd(length/3), lt(90), fd(length/3))
    else:
       peano(level-1, length/2)
       rt(45)
       peano(level-1, length/2)
       rt(-45)
       peano(level-1, length/2)

peano(2, 40)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At its most basic, 0th level, the fractal routine needs to simply draw a straight line using `forward()` (aka `fd()`).  At level 1, it should draw the basic pattern that makes up the fractal, *but* using the fractal routine itself to draw lines, not `forward()`.  Every level above that does the same.  We're replacing line drawing with fractal drawing:

```
from turtle import *

def peano(level, length):
    if level == 0:
        forward(length)
    else:
        angle = 90

        peano(level-1, length/3)

        right(angle)
        peano(level-1, length/3)

        for _ in range(2):
            for _ in range(3):
                left(angle)
                peano(level-1, length/3)

            angle = -angle

        left(angle)
        peano(level-1, length/3)

# Starting position and angle to fill our window
penup()
goto(-220, 220)
pendown()
right(45)

peano(2, 600)

exitonclick()
```

You don't need the nested loops that I added, you can write out the steps explicitly:

```
    else:
        peano(level-1, length/3)

        right(90)
        peano(level-1, length/3)

        left(90)
        peano(level-1, length/3)
        left(90)
        peano(level-1, length/3)
        left(90)
        peano(level-1, length/3)

        right(90)
        peano(level-1, length/3)
        right(90)
        peano(level-1, length/3)
        right(90)
        peano(level-1, length/3)

        left(90)
        peano(level-1, length/3)
```

[image]